# How can I pass data to another controller using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to try to pass data that was taken from an api:

**Javascript:**

```
 function RecentCars($scope, $http){
        $scope.cars = [];
        $http({method:'GET'; url:'/recent'}).success(function(data,status){
                $scope.cars = data;
        });
        $scope.clickThatCar =function(){
                // want to pass that cars data to the CarPage Controller

        }
    }

    function CarPage($scope, data){
       // get the data for the car that was clicked 
    }
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="motor in cars">
       <div class="car_row" ng-click="clickThatCar()">
           <img class="car_img" src="/images/{{motor._id}}_0.jpg">
           <div class="car_info">
               <span class="brand_name">{{motor.brand}}</span>
               <span class="price">4,200 KD</span>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Im listing some cars using ng-repeat and that bit works fine, however when i click clickThatCar element, I want to  just pass the data for the car that was clicked only. Im really new to angular :(

Comment: A quick google search, gave me 4 duplicates from Stackoverflow alone, [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508666/sharing-a-variable-between-controllers-in-angular-js), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227090/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js).

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand sorry i really appreciate you searching, but my problem is quite specific i have tried searching for it on google.

Comment: @user2681696 its not even a bit specific. Its exactly the same problem. Use services and you are done.

Comment: Nope, your problem is not specific at all from what you describe, just declare some backing variable in a service and share that service between your controllers, [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21452417/189756).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the car info in the `ng-click` call. Your code would look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="motor in cars">
    <div class="car_row" ng-click="clickThatCar(motor)">
        <img class="car_img" src="/images/{{motor._id}}_0.jpg">
        <div class="car_info">
            <span class="brand_name">{{motor.brand}}</span>
            <span class="price">4,200 KD</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```