# How to display a value from another controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have Two modules namely Authentication and Home and they have there own controllers.each of them have same name controllers.js

I have to display value like $scope.username in home page (module Home) which is comes from controller of module Authentication .How it possible??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs sharing data between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227090/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. I would prefer you to make an `app.factory('dataFactory' , func(){..})` and `get/set` data there and retrieve your value in any module through out the app.

```
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
        var _name = '';
    return {
        getName: function(text){
            return _name;
        },
        setName: function(name){
            _name = name;
        }  
    }               
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/k3phygpz/871/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: my question is to set $scopename=Admin and want it to call from home page as {{$scopename}}.Then what I have to change in your above code?

Comment: Nothing. You just have to call `testFactory.getName()` to retrieve your name variable in your `homeController`. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/k3phygpz/872/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared service instead which will return your value and the in your controller(s) inject that service as dependency.

e.g.

```
angular.module( 'yourApp' )
    .value("username", "Jon")
    .controller("index", ["$scope", "username", function($scope, username) {
      $scope.username = username;
    }]);
```

or by use of factory recipe:

```
angular.module( 'yourApp' )
    .factory("username", function(){
       var value = 'John';
       return {
         get: function(){
            return value;
         },
         set: function(newName){
           value = newName;
         }
       }
    })
    .controller("index", ["$scope", "username", function($scope, username) {
      $scope.username = username.get();
    }]);
```

If this value will be dynamic you can save value as object and return reference, then you won't need to use manually created watches to see if value changed:

```
angular.module( 'yourApp' )
    .factory("username", function(){
       var username = {
          value: 'John'
       };
       return {
         get: function(){
            return username;
         },
         set: function(newName){
           username.value = newName;
         }
       }
    })
    .controller("index", ["$scope", "username", function($scope, username) {
      $scope.usernameObj = username.get();
    }]);
```

and in view:

```
   {{usernameObj.value}}
```

you can also do that by use of prototypical inheritance of `$scope` by saving value in parent scope.